# Swiftmailer BCCing 500 users

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

There are 500 unique users in our system and we have created a notification system that will send all the users a plain-text email when there is an update to one of the sections. The system uses swiftmailer and creates an email object and then BCCs the 500 users before sending it.

I just want some reassurance that BCCing 500 users means the server will consider this as sending out 1 email but to a lot of users. I don't want to run into any email limit restrictions set by my server host.

Comment: it's still 500 users getting emails, so it will count as 500 emails. You only submit a single email, but 500 emails go out the other end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will *not* count as one email. The fact that the content of the message is the same is irrelevant, as you still have 500 recipients. In addition, your host's email server probably caps the number of BCC recipients per message at a more reasonable value, so I'd be surprised if you could even do this at all. This sort of blast should be sent via individual messages. If your host balks at the volume, you'll likely have to go to a delivery service like Constant Contact et al.

Comment: thanks. would it be a better method to create a db table, add each email as a row and process them using a cron script? perhaps sending one email every 5/10 seconds?

Comment: It would almost certainly not be better -- it's a ton of additional extra work that adds unneeded complexity and it will gain you nearly nothing, as any modern mail server should be able to queue 500 emails without a hiccup. If your host throttles you, you can simply add a tiny delay in each iteration of your send loop (5-10 seconds per is *way* to long) -- no need to add a database in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to send 1000 emails using this method of BCC and it seemed that the limit for me was around 100 emails. So don't use this. Instead try to use the plugin that SwiftMailer provides.

Here is some sample code:

```
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance(
  Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)
);

// Use AntiFlood to re-connect after 100 emails
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(100));

// And specify a time in seconds to pause for (30 secs)
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(100, 30));

$content = 'email body'

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Email subject')
            ->setFrom(array('no-reply@email.com'=> 'From me'))
            ->setBody($content,'text/html');

$emails = array('email1@email.com','email2@email.com','email3@email.com');

foreach($emails as $recipient){
   $message->setTo($recipient);
   $mailer->send($message);
}
```

I hope this helps with your problem as a simpler solution.